# Docker volume multiple directories in to one directory in docker machine

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I might be trying a stupid idea but I believe there should be the solution.

My question is I want to bind multiple subdirectories into one folder under docker-machine, like:

Volume:

- ../folder1:/var/www/html/app/module
- ../folder2:/var/www/html/app/module

Something like this. I googled it. Didn't find something related.

Comment: This configuration produces error?

Comment: Duplicate mount points:

Comment: You cannot mount multiple folders on the same path inside a container or anywhere for the sake, however you should be able to mount these folders in subPath under module as module/folder1 module/folder2